# Get input from user and print decreasing pattern of numbers

Tags: java

Can someone help me write a code that prints the following pattern.

```
987654321
 98765432
  9876543
   987654
    98765
     9876
      987
       98
        9
```

This is my code sample but I am getting the exact opposite of the above pattern.

```
        height = getInPut("Enter the height of the triangle");
        int h = Integer.parseInt(height);
        int start = h, num=1,max=h;
        
        for (int r= 1; r <=h; r++)
        {
            System.out.println();
            for (int j = 1; j<= max; j++)
            {
                if(h>=6 && h<=10) 
                {
                    System.out.print(num);  
               }else{
                   System.out.println("height should be between 6-10");
                   System.exit(0);
               }
                
              num++;
            }
           num= r+1;
           max--;
            }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @Elliott Frisch . A very good solution however it is not specific to what I am asking. I mean let me get a user input a number between 6 and 10 then print the numbers in a decreasing order thus forming that inverted triangle. Thats why I have the statement "height = getInPut("Enter the height of the triangle");" this tells the user to input the height of of the triangle and the program prints out that shape.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with an initial value of `987654321` in a `StringBuilder`, then loop while that contains characters; in every iteration of the loop, we want to print the difference (in spaces) between the initial length (nine) and the current length of the `StringBuilder`, then print the contents of the `StringBuilder` before removing the last character. Like,

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("987654321");
while (sb.length() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9 - sb.length(); i++) {
        System.out.print(' ');
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
    sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
}
```

Which outputs (as requested)

```
987654321
 98765432
  9876543
   987654
    98765
     9876
      987
       98
        9
```

I'll leave filling the initial `StringBuilder` and adjusting nine into a variable as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I can't help thinking it would be quite useful to help OP understand the mistakes they've made, and point them towards fixing up their own solution.  Unlike actually doing their homework for them, using an entirely different technique, which frankly benefits nobody.